# PHP page not reloading automatically after deleting record?

Tags: php, caching, reload

After the record deletion i have send header to previous page but it's not happen how could i solved it..

record is already deleted but it still show in that page after pressing ctrl + f5 when page is reload from server at that time the effect of deletion is show.

```
<?php
     include('../config.php');
    $table=$_REQUEST['table'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id);
    $_SESSION['message']="Deleted Successfully....";

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

also in all the pages happening same thing adter edit add and all the data base action is showing effect after ctrl+f5 press...

Comment: Paste your code here.

Comment: i have edit the question plz show it ...? it is properly working while project is in localhost...

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the variable `$id`

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id); // Where is $id initialized?
```

Did you forget to add

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

If your `$id` is not initialised, definitley, `mysql_query` will execute some query like:

`DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id=`

Which will not conclude to anything and hence, no delete will occur.

Notes:

1) Do not use **mysql_** functions are they are [deprecated and will be removed in upcoming PHP versions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

2) You are feeding a variable coming from `$_REQUEST` directly to your SQL. The variable needs to be [sanitized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: If he is using register_globals then $id will be probably initialized.
Anakbhai: put a
print mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$id);
in the first line, so you see the query that is sent to the database...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
window.location.href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>"; 
</script>
```